# Trigger.io Forge 2.2.0 iOS "Non-Public APIs"

Tags: ios, trigger.io

After getting caught in the Trigger.io Forge 2.2.0 upgrade today, and re-building our app for App-store distribution, I encountered this error:

"The app links to non-public libraries in Payload/device-ios.app/Forge: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit"

Anyone know how to fix this?  We don't use any non-public trigger.io modules.

Comment: An update:  2.2.1 fixes the problem, but it also forces you to drop support for iOS 4.3 and 5 (minimum iOS version of 6.0).  That's OK for us, but YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger IO just released an update for this today. https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html

Comment: Yes, it looks like 2.2.0 was buggy (as many .0 releases are).   Hopefully 2.2.1 will do the trick!